# Proper way to navigate fragments with Navigation within DrawerLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, navigator, drawerlayout

Im kinda new to jetpack component.. i was studying the navigator and hit a wall.. bc theres gotta be a elegant way to handle moving within all posible scenarios in a navigator within a drawer layout, but i cant manage to find it..
guide "https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#kotlin" doesnt work as "The drawer icon is displayed on all top-level destinations that use a DrawerLayout" is false, so i had to added manually a toolbar so the other link "https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer" doesnt work either.

i got a drawerlayout with 4 items..(from a menu file)

i got the navcontroller:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as 
NavHostFragment

val navController = navHostFragment.navController
```

from drawer layout i can go from homeFragment->A or B or C using navController.navigate(...)
But once i navigate to another Fragment, i need another action for the case i want to navigate from fragment A->B

So my solution simplified is :

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
val currentFragment = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments[0]

if (currentFragment is HomeFragment ){
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.myProfile -> {
                    navController.navigate(...)
                }
                R.id.people -> {
                    navController.navigate(...)
                }
                ...// other options
            }
        } 
 if (currentFragment is A_Fragment ){
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.myProfile -> {
                    navController.navigate(...)
                }
                ....//all other options
            }
        }
```

As you can see, this works..  but i guess theres gotta be a better way to do the navigation within the drawer layout.. right?

BTW, i saw the guide and it doesnt work, but may be the issue is here:
"The drawer icon is displayed on all top-level destinations that use a DrawerLayout"
which is false. i just copied-pasted the layout into main_activity.xml layout and it doesnt show anything,
Im thinking may be the dependency im using is incorrect.

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Why are you doing any of this when [the guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) shows you how to use `setupWithNavController()`, which does all this for you by [tying destinations to menu items](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)?

Comment: hi ianhanniballake, Thank you for your comment.   and as i added in the question, with current dependencies i have, the guide does not work in many places.  Thats why i had to add a <code>androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar</code> into my xml in order to show the burger icon.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't followed the [guide for the top app bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar) either then? Are you using any of the `setup` methods provided? If not, why not?